# No current conversation available. Create a conversation and bind it to the container

Tags: nhibernate, repository

I get this error when directly use code below in a method:

```
var fooRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FooRepository>();
var fooObj = fooRepository.GetFooObj(someText);  //get Error
```

And the StackTrace contains :

> at uNhAddIns.SessionEasier.Conversations.ThreadLocalConversationalSessionContext.CurrentSession()
>      at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetCurrentSession()

Error Message:

> No current conversation available. Create a conversation and bind it to the container

Generally how to `Create a conversation and bind it to the container`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but find that, if I declare the repository in a model like this

```
[PersistenceConversational(MethodsIncludeMode = MethodsIncludeMode.Implicit)]
public class FooModel : IFooModel
```

and declare a method, use repository mehod in it and return data:

```
class FooModel
{
     public FooObj ModelGetFooObj(string text)
     {
         return fooRepository.GetFooObj(text);
     }
}
```

then new a `FooModel` and use `fooModel.ModelGetFooObj(text)` to get data, works fine.